# Lua - trouble understanding OOP

Tags: lua

I'm having quite a bit of trouble understanding OOP in Lua. According to Programming in Lua, I can create classes very simply, like this:

```
Class = {}

function Class:new()
  setmetatable({}, self)
  self.__index = self

  self.a = 1

  return self
end

function Class:incr()
  self.a = 2 * self.a
  return self
end
```

However, when I go and create an instance, it doesn't work as I would expect:

```
-- works as expected
instance = Class:new()
instance:incr()
print(instance) --> table 0x(address)
print(instance.a) --> 2

-- it gets weird from here on
other = Class:new()
other:incr():incr()
print(other) --> table 0x(same address)
print(other.a) --> 4

print(instance.a) --> 4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the weird part?

Comment: @PatrickSturm Perhaps I worded this a bit incorrectly, what I meant is that a new object is not created.

Answer (score 1):

The example in PiL is frankly confusing. It describes what's called *prototypal inheritance*. That means that there's no distinction between classes and objects. Here is a version of your `new` method which is slightly more correct:

```
function Class:new()
  -- Note that self refers to the class, here. We have to return a new object.
  self.__index = self
  local o = {a=1}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  return o
end
```

But we still have a problem: Since our constructor sets an instance variable, we can't use it to make subclasses. If we try, those subclasses will all have `a` set within themselves, instead of in their instances. We could define an `init` method that we have to call every time we create a new instance, but that would be a pain. Here is one possible way to keep classes and objects separate:

```
-- Make sure every class has an __index pointing to itself. This lets it be the
-- metatable for both instances and subclasses.
local Class = {}
Class.__index = Class

function Class:new()
  local o = {a=1}
  setmetatable(o, self)
  return o
end

function Class:incr()
  self.a = 2 * self.a
  return self
end

-- To inherit, simply use Class as the metatable.
local Subclass = {}
Subclass.__index = Subclass
setmetatable(Subclass, Class)
```

This way, `new` is used only for creating instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Class:new()
...
   return self -- self is -> Class = {}
end

other    = Class:new() -- Other will get Class = {} when you call new()
instance = Class:new() -- same here
print(other)    -- will print Class = {}
print(instance) -- will print Class = {}
```